# Python shows me an Error (Out of Bounds) when running the DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am trying to change the columns 'check in' and 'check out' to Datetime.
When I run the code below I get the error message 'Out of bounds nanosecond' (picture attached as well). Can anybody help me, how I can get rid of this problem please?

Thank you in advance!

```
expedia2013_2014["srch_co"] = pd.to_datetime(expedia2013_2014["srch_co"])   
expedia2013_2014["srch_ci"] = pd.to_datetime(expedia2013_2014["srch_ci"])
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables of *Timestamp* type can hold dates roughly from years in range (1677, 2262).
You attempt to convert date from year **2557**, so it is out of range.
You have to use other date format.

One of possible options: If you have the source date as a **string**,
e.g. `src='2557-08-17'`, you can run:

```
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(src, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you have a DataFrame with source column named *Dat* (as string), you can
convert it running:

```
df.Dat = df.Dat.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date())
```

When you print *df*, it is printed just the same way, but when you read it
calling `df.loc[some_index,'Dat']`, the result will be
`datetime.date(2557, 8, 17)`.